# Twigmo custom style files

Tags: css, cs-cart

did anyone ever customize the Twigmo addon basic theme for cs-cart? I am trying to write custom css files for font size and color. What I tried:

1. Using the visual Editor: after working for like 2 hours changing the styles, I tried saving and apparently my current subscription doesn't allow me to do custom files using visual editor
2. I tried searching for other solutions: fell on this [twigmo skin editing](http://forum.cs-cart.com/topic/30992-change-look-of-twigmo-skin/) which basically tells me to create a custom css file called custom{theme-name}.css. I did but i still can't figure out what classes the twigmo for what. Does anyone know where i can find this? i am also posting a question on the forum to see if they can help me.

Thank-you in advance. hope my question is clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The free "Starter" Twigmo subscription plan doesn't provide an ability to customize CSS. You have to subscribe for any paid plan. In this case the visual editor will be available for you. Also you will be able to write your custom CSS code in the visual editor.

Regarding your second solution - it is for old version and doesn't work for the Twigmo 3.x.

Hovewer you can modify the `design/themes/[your_theme]/templates/addons/twigmo/mobile_index.tpl` file. You can add your CSS code there. It is not the most convenient way, but it is free.